# clear the EE cache with cron job

Tags: admin, cache, cache-folder, cron

What's the best way to clear the EE cache periodically without having to do it manually on sites?

I know there's the Cron Clean Cache plugin but was looking for something more like a system URL that we could hit on a CURL request in cron.

Or is setting up a template with this plugin the only route?

Comment: could I ask what your end solution was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Bhashkar said, that code should work in either a PHP-enabled template or put in a plugin and then put in a template. Then call the template to clear cache.

A more advanced way, and probably the proper way to do it, is to create a simple module, which can use an Action URL. Stephen Lewis [wrote a blog post about what Actions are](http://experiencehq.net/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-expressionengine-actions). Basically, an action maps a url like `http://domain.com/index.php?ACT=123` (where 123 is the action ID) to any method in your module. You can use it to trigger the cache clearing.

Say you add this method to your `mod.my_addon.php` file:

```
public function clear_cache()
{
    $this->EE->functions->clear_caching('all', '', TRUE);
    die('Cache cleared');
}
```

Then in your `upd.my_addon.php` file, inside the `install()` method, you need to add the action. Something like this:

```
$this->EE->db->insert('actions', array(
    'class'  => 'My_addon',
    'method' => 'clear_cache'
));
```

Where `My_addon` is the name of the class in the `mod.my_addon.php` file and `clear_cache` refers to the method you want to execute.

You could even add a check in your own `clear_cache` method for something like a secret key, so URL-hackers can't accidentally (or deliberately) trigger it.

Sounds like something one could learn in a certain workshop. ;)

Comment: dude - I'm gutted to be missing the workshop! I'd have definitely been there if not for the impending arrival. The action route is what I had in mind given we have other crons to hit other Action URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Steven,

You can have the following code within a template (PHP allowed):

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
$cache_type = 'all'; // It can be 'page' OR 'tag' OR 'db' OR 'sql' OR 'relationships'
$this->EE->functions->clear_caching($cache_type, '', TRUE);
```

and schedule template URL call with CRON job. I think, this would be the simplest solution for you.

*For EE v2.+*

Comment: meh, I don't like enabling PHP in templates when I don't have to. I'd be as well using the plugin and calling the same template without having PHP enabled.

Comment: Yes, it would be fine to develop plugin having the code for clearing cache and call within template.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this module to trigger the cache clearing using Action ID
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/beanstalk-web-hook
[image]